# Deleting the line, but not the content below, if its child contains specific element

Tags: xml, xslt, parent-child

I am trying to change an XML layout in such a way that:

Whenever the node in the code is followed by a child with Product UserTypeID (in other words, the direct child does not contain any  attributes, then I would like to delete "OBJ_TEST_5".  However, I still want to keep the content of the children with  attributes!

Original XML:

```
  <Products>
    <Product ID="B5_123123" UserTypeID="OBJ_TEST_5" ParentID="OBJ_TEST_4">
      <Product ID="CB_1233434" UserTypeID="OBJ_childBelow" ParentID="OBJ_TEST_5">
        <Product ID="GCB_9162375" UserTypeID="OBJ_grandChildBelow">
          <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="TESTATTR">Classification 1 root/ Gelbe Struktur/ G1_222338/ / / </Value>
            <Value AttributeID="TESTATTR2">TRIAL retrans</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="TESTATTR3">TRIAL2</Value>
          </Values>
        </Product>
      </Product>
    </Product>
  </Products>
```

Adjusted with XSLT:

```
  <Products>
        <Product ID="GCB_9162375" UserTypeID="OBJ_grandChildBelow">
          <Values>
            <Value AttributeID="TESTATTR">TRIAL1</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="TESTATTR2">TRIAL2 retrans</Value>
            <Value AttributeID="TESTATTR3">TRIAL3</Value>
          </Values>
        </Product>
      </Product>
    </Product>
  </Products>
```

The XSLT that I have at this point of time includes:

```
<xsl:template match="Product[@UserTypeID='OBJ_TEST_5']">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Product[@UserTypeID='OBJ_childBelow']">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Product[@UserTypeID='OBJ_grandChildBelow']">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this seems to delete all content!

Can any of you help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are the only templates in your XSLT, then you also need to add the identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or in XSLT 3.0, do this...

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

As for your existing templates, you don't want the one that matches "OBJ_grandChildBelow" as you don't want that deleted. The other two templates could probably be combined into one more generic one too..

```
<xsl:template match="Product[not(Values)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Product[not(Values)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! 

However, I forgot to add that the number of parents can differ (they won't always be OBJ_TEST_5 followed by OBJ_childBelow followed by OBJ_grandChildBelow). It could be that OBJ_childBelow is not listed and that OBJ_grandChildBelow lies directly under OBJ_TEST_5.

How can I include this conditional factor?

Comment: So, you want to delete all Products apart from "OBJ_grandChildBelow"?

Comment: I would like to add a conditional statement where an element is removed if it does not contain any values (i.e. it is followed directly by another Product).  This must happen up to the point where an element does contain values.  So in my example above, the element with ProductUserID OBJ_TEST_5 did not contain values and neither did OBJ_childBelow.  As a result I would like these removed

Comment: I have amended my answer.

Comment: Great! Thanks Tim C :)